# How to pass DataFrame as input to Spark UDF?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I have written code in python for eg:
environment:Zeppelin

```
def variabletype(dataframe):
   df = dataframe
   num_col_list=['int','float']
   numerical_columns ##etc
   return cols_list_df

variabletype(df)
```

I need to apply same function on pyspark dataframe how to do that?

Comment: Please properly format your code and edit the question so that people can understand it better, enclose the code in ``` so that you get the proper formatting

Answer (score 0):

Use the same method you are using currently, for eg

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'], 'string').toDF("Data")

def print_cols(df):
    print(df.columns)
    
print_cols(df)
```

Output:

```
['Data']
```

Comment: No iam using zeppelin so when i pass pyspark dataframe  to a python function it shows following error ,  invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in swapping_population
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in bucket_creation
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 661, in select
    'invalid entry {} in condlist: should be boolean ndarray'.format(i))
ValueError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray

Comment: Never used zeppelin so can't comment on this, you should also mention you are using zeppelin in the question it would be helpful for the people answering

Comment: You should also include this error and the pysparl code in your original question. This has nothing to do with Zeppelin but might be related to Pyspark indeed. Or more likely with the data you are working on.